# Yii2 friendly urls doesn't work

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I'm using Yii2 advanced and Nginx. My urlmanager:

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [
        'test1' => 'page/view?id=1',
        'test2' => 'page/view?id=2',
    ],
],
```

mydomain.com/page/view?id=1 - it works

mydomain.com/test1 - doesn't work. 404 error

It worked in Yii1 but doesn't work in Yii2. What's wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set array of default parameters in defaults property.

```
'rules' => [
    [
        'pattern' => 'test1',
        'route' => 'page/view',
        'defaults' => ['id' => 1],
    ],
],
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions for parameters in a rules:

```
'rules' => [
    'test/<id:\d+>' => 'page/view',
],
```

Also read Yii2 docs about **Routing and URL Creation** http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html#routing

Comment: No, my question is how can I use mydomain.com/test instead mydomain.com/page/view?id=1 I don't need id in url

Comment: In that case much better to create a single page for each test1 and test2 urls and then you can describe it like `'test1' => 'page/test1', 'test2' => 'page/test2'`. As for your path _page/view?id=1_ with **?id=1**, it assumes that **id** must be present in your rules, that's why we recommended you to use regexp.

Answer (score 0):

In your `urlManager` config, you should define only controller and action.

So your `rules` will be:

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [
        'test1' => 'page/view',
        'test2' => 'page/view',
    ],
],
```

You can run via link `@baseUrl/test1?id=1` and `@baseUrl/test2?id=2`, or use this `urlHelper` in your view:

```
Html::a('test1', \yii\helpers\Url::to(['test1', 'id' => 1]))
```

If you want to `test1` show page view with `id=1`, `test2` will show with `id=2`, you should config rule like that:

```
'rules' => [
     //other rules ...
     [
         'pattern' => 'test<id:\d+>',
         'route' => 'page/view',
     ],
     //other rules ...
],
```

Hope this useful.

Goodluck and have fun.

Comment: I don't need id in url. It should be like this: `domain.com/download` - `domain.com/page/view?id=1` or `domain.com/test` - `domain.com/page/view?id=2` etc.